# Как получить список всех полей значимых типов у класса?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Недавно открыл для себя даппер и теперь пишу свой репозиторий(велосипед) для него. В ходе написания встала необходимость получить список всех значимых полей класса, не помеченных аттрибутом [NotMapped].

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос попытками, как Вы сами пытались справиться с заданием. [**Почему это нужно (на англ.)**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Спасибо.

Comment: Через рефлексию. [GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx), [Type.Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx), [Type.IsValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.isvaluetype(v=vs.110).aspx), [Type.GetFields()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx)